# Tutorial about syntax of HoTT variant of Coq

Tags: types, coq, homotopy-type-theory

I'd like to learn the Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT) variant of Coq. I am browsing the web site http://homotopytypetheory.org/, I have installed the variant of Coq, and I would like to play a little bit with it, write down the examples of the book, etc... But I cannot find a pdf/html file explaining the basic syntax. When I try in hoqide (the HoTT variant of coqide) the piece of code

```
Require Import HoTT.
Inductive circle:Type1 := | ZERO : circle | loop : ZERO = ZERO.
```

I get the error "Error: The reference ZERO was not found in the current environment." I guess that I don't load enough libraries, or maybe that `ZERO = ZERO` is not the correct notation for the type of paths from ZERO to itself.
In the blog, the notations `ZERO ~~> ZERO` and `Paths ZERO ZERO` are also used, but they don't work here. Where can I find a tutorial to start ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any tutorials in the style you are looking for, but as far as I know HoTT doesn't really change the syntax of inductive types in Coq. Instead, they use a feature known as *private inductive types* in addition to axioms to define higher inductive types while maintaining consistency. For instance, see how [the circle is defined](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/theories/HIT/Circle.v) in the HoTT library itself.

Comment: OK. I change the question. How can I define the circle with a base point and a loop having the type of a path. The piece of code Require Import HoTT.
Private Inductive S1 : Type1 :=
| base : S1
| loop : base = base. gives the error message Error: The type of constructor loop
 is not valid; it must be "S1".

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher Sorry for missing this; here's a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/homotopytypetheory/hit$20implementation/homotopytypetheory/Wf6G_ahaHkY/OVOjL3gPKK0J) I found on the HoTT mailing list about exactly this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the HoTT-enabled variant of Coq, but when you define an inductive type like `circle`, all your constructors must actually construct elements of that type. You can't write e.g.

```
Inductive mytype : Type :=
  | foo1 : mytype        (* ok *)
  | foo2 : nat -> mytype (* ok *)
  | foo3 : nat -> False  (* urk! Not ok. *)
  | foo3 : nat -> 0 = 1  (* urk! Not ok. *)
  .
```

otherwise the logic would become inconsistent quite fast. Now, you might think that since `ZERO = ZERO` is a theorem, assuming that a proof of that exists is harmless, but Coq can't automatically realize that. Further, such a proof is surely not a constructor of `ZERO`. Probably a better alternative is to use e.g.

```
Variable foo3 : ZERO = ZERO .
```

or one of the similar commands (`Axiom,Hypothesis,...`).

Comment: ZERO = ZERO is supposed above to be the type of paths from ZERO to ZERO, not a theorem. It is why I asked the question: what is the syntax ? I still do not know the answer. A higher inductive type in HoTT is freely generated by some points and paths and higher dimensional paths. That does not exist in the standard Coq indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There is [an old branch of Bruno Barras' fork of Coq](https://github.com/barras/coq/tree/hit) that allows syntax roughly like that.  See, for example, in [the example file hit-hoh.v](https://github.com/barras/coq/blob/1aaca5c1e6a15d57a3008d5ca86e33fb34681c69/hit-hoh.v):

```
Inductive circle : U :=
   base
// loop : base=base.
```

Alas, this version of Coq has not been updated since late 2015, and there is no such native support in the current version of Coq.

The way [the HoTT library](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT) codes higher inductive types is with the extension of private inductives.  For example, [in an older version of the circle file](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/a3b9edb4909d02c7a445e683e3b27801429e8292/theories/hit/Circle.v) (which has since been replaced with a definition via coequaliziers), we can see:

```
Module Export Circle.

Private Inductive S1 : Type1 :=
| base : S1.

Axiom loop : base = base.

Definition S1_ind (P : S1 -> Type) (b : P base) (l : loop # b = b)
  : forall (x:S1), P x
  := fun x => match x with base => fun _ => b end l.

Axiom S1_ind_beta_loop
  : forall (P : S1 -> Type) (b : P base) (l : loop # b = b),
  apD (S1_ind P b l) loop = l.

End Circle.
```

The `Private Inductive` keyword tells Coq to disable pattern matching outside the current module; this allows us to force users to use only elimination/induction principles defined in the given module.  We then axiomatize the path constructors, axiomatize their computation rules, and define the eliminator.  Note that the eliminator must make use of the path argument (`l : loop # b = b`) in its body, or else Coq will assume that what you pass as that argument doesn't matter.

~~~~~

> Where can I find a tutorial to start ?

I am not aware of any such tutorial at present, but I might suggest looking at [`contrib/HoTTBook.v`](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/contrib/HoTTBook.v) and [`contrib/HoTTBookExercises.v`](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/contrib/HoTTBookExercises.v) which contain many links between the HoTT book / exercises and the HoTT/HoTT library.  Looking at how these theorems and exercises are stated and proven might be useful (and feel free to contribute your own solutions/proofs to problems/theorems that are not linked to anything yet!).